# kendo ui Q3 grid export to excel built in not working?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Hi every one I'm using my web app kendo ui grid export to excel built in, its not saving any record,
I mentioned it like

```
toolbar: ["excel"],
        excel: {
            allPages: true
    },
```

//and

```
toolbar: ["excel"],
        excel: {
            fileName: "Kendo UI Grid Export.xlsx",
            proxyURL: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export",
            filterable: true
        },
```

I'm just confused about proxy url? what it means ?

Answer (score 3):

You need this to support Internet Explorer versions below 10 and Safari 
Please review [Server Proxy Implementations](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/save-files/introduction#server-proxy-implementations) samples (.NET, PHP, Java)

> Internet Explorer versions below 10 and Safari can't save a file and
>   require the implementation of a server proxy. Set the proxyURL option
>   to specify the server proxy URL.

In ASP.NET MVC the function will be something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ExportButtonSave(string contentType, string base64, string fileName)
        {
            var fileContents = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

            return File(fileContents, contentType, fileName);
        }
```

Please note that all you need to make the export work is add it to toolbar even if you don't add it to grid, check http://dojo.telerik.com/@MohQut/OdEpE